# Excluding arm64 architecture leads to 'No such module: AWSAppSync'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, aws-appsync, arm64

I am currently working on a Swift 5.0 project (Xcode 12). I currently use an M! computer. For my project, I have a couple of pod dependencies that I need (AWS, Google, etc) to make my project work. When I run my code on a IOS device, I encounter no issues. But when I try to run the project on a simulator, I run into different errors involving the pod linking.

The Google places autocomplete FAQ says that if I have troubles building on an iOS simulator using Xcode 12, I should exclude the arm64 architecture for iOS simulators by altering the project build settings. But upon doing that, I get a warning of "No such module found: AWSAppSync".

In attempting to fix this, I've added 'x86_64' and 'x86' to architectures, set "Build Active Architecture Only" to "yes", and made sure my pod's build settings have the same "Build Active Architecture Only" value, which results in no change. I have also tried pod update, install, install --repo-update, cleaning the build folder, deleting derived data, and restarting Xcode.

When I set "Build Active Architecture Only" to "No" for both sets of build settings (pod and project), I get another error from a different non-AWS pod:
"Could not find module 'MultiSlider' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios-simulator"

Removing any code references to the multi slider then lets the app fully build, but the app crashes before launching on the simulator with an error of "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000067fd90".

Note that with any of these attempted fixes, the app continues to run on an actual iOS device as expected. I'm very new to pods and would really appreciate any help or insight anyone could offer! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had to exclude the arm64 architecture for each of the pods when building for the simulator. See https://narlei.com/development/apple-m1-xcode-error-when-build-in-simulator/ for more details, but it seems that excluding arm64 from the project AND excluding it in the Podfile for each pod's target is necessary.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES'
      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
     end
  end
end
```